# What's the best way to check the result of calling the Perl open function?

Tags: perl

I have code in perl that runs the following:

```
sub runMyCommand{
  my $filename ="testing.txt"
  foreach my $arg (@_) {
    my $path = catfile($arg, $filename);
    if(open my $fh, ">" , $path){
      print $fh "my path is :\$pah\n"
      close $fh;
    }else{
      ....
    }
  }
} 

runMyCommand("/opt/");
```

for some reason this keeps going to the else part all the time. Even though I can go to /opt/ and write a file. Is there something wrong with the way I am using open?

thank you,

Comment: Better: `warn("Can't open \"$path\": $!\n");`

Answer (score -1):

A better way to use the open function in Perl is to follow a pattern like this.

```
open my $fh, ">", $path
    or die "failed to open $path: $!"
```

In this way, you get a fatal error with a descriptive message provided by the OS error variable $!.